# get base64 URI result from ACTIVITY_GET_CONTENT (Android)

Tags: android, base64, uri, android-gallery

In an android app I'm developing, I want the user to pick an image from their gallery, and for that, i'm using this code:

```
private void takePictureFromGallery(int pick) {
    startActivityForResult(
            Intent.createChooser(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT).setType("image/*"), "Choose an image"), pick);
}
```

And I'm using onActivityResult to detect when an image has been selected.
Since I want the URI of the image, I call

```
Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
```

But that only returns "/document/image:28" as an output.

What would be the process of instead receiving a Base64-type URI (one that begins with "data:image/gif;base64,{base64 encoded image}") that represents the image?

Thanks In Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
```

That statement is useless. That is akin to thinking that `/questions/34245601/get-base64-uri-result-from-activity-get-content-android` (the path portion of the URL of this Web page) is somehow meaningful in isolation.

> What would be the process of instead receiving a Base64-type URI (one that begins with "data:image/gif;base64,{base64 encoded image}") that represents the image?

Step #1: Use a `ContentResolver` to `openInputStream()` on that `Uri`.

Step #2: Read in the bytes and convert them to base64, appending them to the end of a URL that has your desired prefix.

Step #3: Be prepared for `OutOfMemoryErrors`, as you may not have enough heap space for your string, depending on the state of your heap and the size of the image that the user chooses.